# File cache mechanism: how to intercept network requests

Tags: php, file, caching

I need to create a file cache mechanism. It should implement a [given interface](https://gist.github.com/briedis/d14c4fd416bab8b8b8b873a8d677a0a6).

The caching process is by definition:

> To serve content from the cache and make your app available offline you need to intercept network requests and respond with files stored in the cache.

So, **how to intercept network requests** to arbitrary files? Eg.

- [www.domain.com/abc.php](http://www.domain.com/abc.php)
- [www.domain.com/def.php](http://www.domain.com/def.php)
- [www.domain.com/style.css](http://www.domain.com/style.css)
- etc.

provided the mechanism should do it for any file requested.

### Note 1: single file cache [with injection] is possible

I know how to cache a single file, eg. is [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-a-simple-and-efficient-php-cache), yet to **generalize it for any file**, without injecting cache code into file... but by interrupting a request?

### Note 2, no framework

The task must be dome **without using any framework** (that obviously accommodates input http request pre-processing).

### Note 3: PhpFastCache library (it's though a Laravel library... :-( )

I'm aware of the [PhpFastCache](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache), yet I am not sure if one can apply it in this case, even how to properly apply it.

Comment: I don't know much about caching in your scenario. But Php cache is certainly not going to make your site *available offline*. As even for Php cache to work you have to make a request to server. As for intercepting *network requests* and making site *available offline*, I think this part resides with Javascript service worker. Have a loot at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers and https://dev.to/saurabhdaware/make-websites-work-offline-part-1-what-are-service-workers-and-how-to-get-a-custom-app-install-button-on-the-website-4a8

Comment: @UmairKhan, the site content is **not meant to be available offline**. User makes http request to a server and the server responds with cached files (usually *.html) rather then with processing php files.

Comment: SO is more about answering specific programming questions, this (IMHO) is far to broad and is more about how to go about caching.

Comment: Caching can be done on very different levels, i think you are mixing them up. Can you please clarify the scenario what information you want to cache?

Comment: @thehennyy, "what information" - **files**.

Comment: @NigelRen, where then I might ask this question?

Comment: Caching a php file on network level makes no sense. The code is executed on the server, the file is never transmitted. Only its execution output could be cached, but thats not file caching anymore. To cache content on network level you could use nginx as caching proxy https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/.